# How to present distance data on excel (or retrieve data from excel) while using CPLEX OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have three locations, multiple depots,multiple stops and multiple landfills. All depots, stops and landfills are separate (each starting from 1)? My distance variable d[i][j] (distance between i and j) where i can take any value from depot or stops and landfill. Same is happening with j. How to retrieve such data in .dat file and present in excel so that I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/read2Darrayfromexcel.mod

You may see an example of a 2D array read.
That could be your distance matrix

Comment: There is just one range given, I want to take up 'j' from two ranges either depot or landfill and I have to fetch data from excel.How to do that?